# MySQL Error when I add "Where" in ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

```
ResultSet rsPassword = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT FirstName FROM login.login WHERE CNP = \"" + cnp + "\";");
        if(rsPassword.next()) {
            return rsPassword.getString(1);
}
```

When I modify the ResultSet value without Where, it works. And when i enter the ResultSet value with Where clause in MySQL, it gives the below error. Can you help me?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at databases.database.DataBase.getFirstName(DataBase.java:82)
at LoginInterface.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:17)
at databases.studentInformations.Login.lambda$1(Login.java:67)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
```

Comment: What is `cnp`?  You're treating it like a string but it's probably not

Comment: This much code fragment is not enough to figure out the issue.

Comment: **WARNING**: When composing SQL queries it’s important to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/java) any and all user-data to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This code exposes you to severe risk and should not be deployed.

Comment: `String whateverIndex1IsFor = ""; while (rsPassword.next()) { whateverIndex1IsFor = rsPassword.getString(1); } rsPassword.close(); System.out.println(whateverIndex1IsFor);`